# Chain rule in matrix calculus

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Found some problems with next task.

Given next vector function: $ \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) = A_{[n, m]} \cdot f(B_{[m, n]} \cdot \mathbf{x})$, $~ \mathbf{u}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $A_{[n, m]}$ — matrix with $n$ rows and $m$ columns, and $f(\mathbf{v}) = \left\lbrace f(v_1), \dots, f(v_m) \right\rbrace$. Taking it's derivative wrt $\mathbf{x}$ gives next:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{u}}{d\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}} = B_{[m, n]} \cdot A_{[n, m]} \cdot f'(B_{[m, n]} \cdot \mathbf{x}), ~ \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{[m, n]},
$$
or, it also possible next:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{u}}{d\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}} = A_{[n, m]} \cdot f'(B_{[m, n]} \cdot \mathbf{x}) \cdot (B_{[m, n]})^{\top}, ~ \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{[n, m]}.
$$

So, there is three questions:

1. How can I find derivative more complicated function, such that:
   $$
   \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) = A_{[n, l]} \cdot f(B_{[l, m]} \cdot g(C_{[m, n]} \cdot \mathbf{x}) ), \quad \text{let} ~ \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) = B_{[l, m]} \cdot g(C_{[m, n]} \cdot \mathbf{x}).
   $$
   Next variants are working for this function:
   $$
   \frac{d\mathbf{u}}{d\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}} = C_{[m,n]} \cdot A_{[n, l]} \cdot f'(\mathbf{v}) \cdot ( B_{[l, m]} \cdot g'(C_{[n, m]} \cdot \mathbf{x}) )^{\top}, ~ \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}} : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{[m, l]},
   $$
   or
   $$
   \frac{d\mathbf{u}}{d\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}} = B_{[l, m]} \cdot g'(C_{[m, n]} \cdot \mathbf{x}) \cdot A_{[n, l]} \cdot f'(\mathbf{v}) \cdot ( C_{[m, n]} )^{\top}, ~ \mathbf{u}'_{\mathbf{x}} : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{[l, m]}.
   $$
   Is there a general formula to calculate derivative of more nested functions?
2. Using same idea, how can I calculate second and higher derivatives of these functions?
3. How to calculate any combinations with derivatives, such that $f(x, u, u')$. I think this question can be solved using norms of objects, to use them in estimations as scalars, but don't know, is it a good idea, and how good this approximation will be.

### Update:

For one of these questions founded a solution using a little bit different approach, but correct for this kind of problem. I found that:
$$
u_k = \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{ki} \cdot f\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_{ij} x_j \right)
$$
so:
$$
\frac{du_k}{dx_k} = \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{ki} b_{ik} \cdot f'\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_{ij} x_j \right)
$$
implies approach like in comment below:
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{u}}{d\mathbf{x}} = \sum_{k = 0}^{m} a_{k, *} \cdot \left( f'\left( B_{[m, n]} \cdot \mathbf{x} \right) \odot b_{*, k} \right)
$$
where $a_{k, *}$ — $k$'th row of matrix $A$; $b_{*, k}$ — $k$'th column of matrix $B$, and $A \odot B$ — element-wise product of matrices similar sizes. This formula gives me vector of derivatives in certain point $\mathbf{x}$ with same dimension as initial vector.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$In *Matrix Calculus* it is usually easier to use differentials instead of the Chain Rule. As an example of the technique, let's work through your first problem.

For typing convenience, define the vector variables
$$\eqalign{
y &= Bx &\qiq dy = B\:dx \\
f &= f(y) &\qiq F = \Diag{f} \\
f' &= f'(y) &\qiq df = f'\odot dy = F'\,dy \\
}$$
where $\odot$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product and the `Diag()` function creates a diagonal matrix from its vector argument.

Using the above notation, rewrite the $u$ vector, then calculate its
differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 u &= Af \\
du &= A\:df = AF'\,dy = AF'B\:dx \\
\grad{u}{x} &= AF'B = A\cdot\Diag{f'(Bx)}\cdot B \\
}$$
The idea is to manipulate the differential expression (via backsubstitution of more elementary differentials) into a form wherein the gradient can be readily identified
$$du = G\:dx \qiq \grad{u}{x} = G$$
Since $G$ is a matrix, if you wish to differentiate a second time (to obtain the Hessian) you will encounter a problem:
the gradient of a matrix with respect to a vector is neither a matrix nor a vector, but a **third-order tensor**.
Similarly, matrix-by-matrix differentiation generates fourth-order tensors.
And so on.

The solution is either to abandon matrix-vector notation and use index notation (i.e. componentwise differentiation), or to use [vectorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) to flatten matrix variables into vectors.

Either approach will work, but [index notation](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En221/Notes/Index_notation/Index_notation.htm) is much more flexible.

### Update

For nested function problems, consider the following scenario...

After deriving the above gradient wrt $x,\,$ someone tells you that $x$ is **not** the independent variable, but that $x$ is actually a function of a more primitive variable, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
x &= h = h(Cz) &\qiq u = A\,f\LR{B\:h(Cz)} \\
H &= \Diag{h} \\
}$$
To calculate $\,\large\grad{u}{z}\:$ you would proceed as follows.

First calculate the differential of $x$
$$\eqalign{
dx &= h'\odot\LR{C\,dz} \\
   &= H'C\,dz \\
}$$
Then substitute this into the previously derived expression for $du$
$$\eqalign{
du &= AF'B\;\c{dx} \\
  &= AF'B\;\c{H'C\,dz} \\
\grad{u}{z} &= AF'B\,H'C \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you. I've complete the expression for partial derivatives of this function wrt all $x_k$. Found that:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial x_k} = A_{m, n} \cdot f'(B_{n, m} \mathbf{x}) \cdot B_k \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}
$$
or
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial x_k} = B_k \cdot A_{m, n} \cdot f'(B_{n, m} \mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{R}^{1,1}
$$
Using algorithm above, first variant will be correct.
So, I think higher order tensors for me is not a problem. Now problem with interpret this matrix as vector of scalar values of derivative of scalar $u$ at point $x_k$ of $\mathbf{x}$.